# What is a pop-back ad?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> Popup and **pop-back ads** annoy many web surfers. So do web sites that open a seemingly endless number of windows when the surfer enters a home page. The secret to this madness is using JavaScript to control the browser window. You’ll see how this is done in Chapter 9.

I know what a pop-up ad is. It's a type of browser window which all of a sudden pops up on screen with those annoying advertisements when you're surfing the net. But what is a pop-back ad?

Comment: I think this is not really a question about English. I also think that the book should provide a clear definition of "pop-back ads". I googled for the term and found on 25 results. Many of them are duplicate, and the first hit is this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pop-up ad is one that appears on top of what the user is doing forcing him or her to deal with the unwanted advertisement.  A pop-back ad (also called a pop-under or pop-behind ad) is one that opens stealthily in another window and is not confronted until the user closes the current window to find him- or herself face-to-face with the advertisement.